# Accepting answers to someone else's questions [meta]

Tags: ros, meta

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've noticed that a lot of people don't accept an answer to their question, even if they comment that the solution worked. Is it OK to accept an answer for a question that I didn't ask? Is there a certain amount of time that should pass before doing so?

I have enough karma to accept the answer for others, but before doing that I want to make sure that that's not going against any kind of etiquette. I didn't find anything in the forum or wiki.

Some examples are: https://answers.ros.org/question/232355/tried-to-publish-before-configured-topic-id-125/?answer=232372#post-id-232372 and https://answers.ros.org/question/232187/publishing-multiple-data-types-in-one-ros-topic-in-arduino/?answer=232190#post-id-232190

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/270909/accepting-answers-to-someone-else%27s-questions-%5Bmeta%5D/) by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on ROS Answers with karma: 6155 on 2017-09-14

Post score: 4

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-09-14**:
One (somewhat miserly) approach that maintains a high quality standard would be to mark an answer the answer only if you had the same problem, found the existing question through search, and the answer helped you.  (And there an upvote for the question would have been earned as well)

**Comment by [lucasw](https://answers.ros.org/users/120/lucasw/) on 2017-09-14**:
Other than that make a comment suggesting that the original question asker to mark the answer as correct, and leave it to them.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-18**:
These are two good approaches. Thanks @lucasw

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I can't find the record, but there was a moment where marking un-selected answers was encouraged by the organizers. So I believe you're more than welcomed to accept reasonable answers.

Something related:

- [(unofficial) ROS Answers Cleanup Week 2015](http://www.ros.org/news/2015/06/ros-answers-cleanup-week.html)
- ["try to answer one question each time you're on the site"](http://www.ros.org/news/2014/12/ros-answers-crosses-20000-questions.html) encouraged repeatedly.

Btw, we also have [a github repo](https://github.com/ros-infrastructure/answers.ros.org/issues) regarding the meta issues for Answers website like your question :)

---

Originally posted by [130s](https://answers.ros.org/users/875/130s/) with karma: 10937 on 2017-09-19

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2017-09-27**:
Great, thanks for input. I think that I'll be following this. I wasn't aware of the repo regarding the meta issues for Answers, so thanks for pointing that out to me too and I'll make sure to ask those types of questions there.